# Can't find the Illegal Characters In Path

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that shows a list of file paths (list view). When you click on any list item containing a file path, it assigns it to the `selectedFile` string. So far it is accurately pulling the string from the selection (based on a SelectedIndexChanged event). However when it goes to read the file based on this path (with BinaryFile.ReadString), I am getting an "Illegal Characters in Path" message.I thought it was because of the "\" character so I made "selectedFile" a static file path, and added the "@" before the string. I received the same error.

```
private void pclListView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in pclListView.SelectedItems)
        {
            string selectedFile = pclListView.SelectedItems[0].Text;
            Console.WriteLine(selectedFile);

            try
            {
                //Read the data of the selected file. 
                File.AppendText(BinaryFile.ReadString(selectedFile));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the "BinaryFile.ReadString(string fileName)" that is referenced:

```
public static string ReadString(string filename)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

    return String.Join("", (from i in fileBytes select __byteLookup[i]).ToArray());
}
```

I'm a student, so I am also open to better ways of doing anything as I learn. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try debugging? Set a breakpoint on the offending line `File.AppendText(BinaryFile.ReadString(selectedFile));` and when your program breaks, check the contents of the variable `selectedFile`.

Comment: What is the value of the hard-coded path you said you tried?

Comment: That's a much better approach than `Console.WriteLine`. Thanks for sharing. I forgot how to do this until now. The path actually looks good. I'm reviewing Peter's answer below. Looks like I have bigger issues at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does the following:

1. Gets the name of a file from (apparently) a `ListView` object.
2. Passes that file name to the `ReadString()` method.
3. The `ReadString()` method then reads all of the binary data from the given file.
4. Next, it translates that binary data to a string using some array called `__byteLookup` (presumably an array of hexadecimal string values or something similar).
5. Finally, it returns that string and passes it to the `File.AppendText()` method.

At step #5, there are two serious problems:

1. You are ignoring the return value of the `AppendText()` method, which is what would let you actually *append* something (i.e. by using the returned `StreamWriter` to write something to the file).

But much worse:

2. You are passing that generated string as the file name. Without seeing the declaration for `__byteLookup` it's impossible to say exactly what there is as an illegal character for a file name. But it's easy to say that there must be *something* there that's invalid.

Unfortunately, there's not enough detail in your question to know exactly what you meant to do. I.e. you seem to want to append the text to some file. But what file that might be, I can't say. Nor can I say how you should append the text. It's not clear from your question how you wanted to actually use the string returned from the `ReadString()` method. Maybe you meant to append that string to some other file? Maybe you did want to use that string somehow to generate a *valid* file name, to which file you'd append some *different* text? Not clear at all.

The only thing that is clear is that using that string as a file name isn't the right thing to do. :)

If from the above you are unable to figure out exactly how to fix the code, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details on how to improve your question so that a better answer can be provided.

Comment: You're right. I'm trying to get better at asking questions. The issue is that my file contained a NULL character. You clued me in when you said "Without seeing the declaration for `__byteLookup`"

I'll keep working on asking clearer questions. And if I can find a way to clarify my question I will.